# Как при клике на кластер получить данные меток в этом кластере? (яндекс карты 2.1)

Tags: яндекс-карты, координаты, кластер

Сценарий: при клике на кластер необходимо выводить информацию в зависимости от того какие метки находятся в данном сегменте кластеризации.

На минимальном зуме (один кластер) это соответственно будут все метки на карте.
При увеличении зума кластеры размножаются и под каждым находятся метки конкретного, кластеризированного участка карты. Как получать их данные при кликах на кластеры соответсвенно?

Сейчас при клике на любой кластер получаю данные всех меток на карте и это понятно - технически они все в одном общем кластере.
Какой может вообще алгоритм решения? Создавать отдельные кластеры под отдельные группы меток и потом объединять в общий кластер?

Спасибо сразу )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается не через клик событие по кластеру, а через boundschange, определением меток в видимой части карты после клика.

```
var geoObjects = cluster.getGeoObjects();
var geoObjectsQuery = ymaps.geoQuery(geoObjects);

// Сразу же показываем список видимых гео-объектов. 
refreshVisibleList();

// Обновляем список видимых гео-объектов при изменении видимой области.
map.events.add('boundschange', function() { 
  refreshVisibleList();
});

function refreshVisibleList() {
// С помощью geoQuery получаем список объектов на карте.
var visibleGeoObjects = geoObjectsQuery.searchIntersect(map);

// Собираем данные из видимых гео-объектов.
var visibleObjectsHtml = [];
visibleGeoObjects.each(function(x) {
var iconContent = x.properties.get('iconContent');
visibleObjectsHtml.push(iconContent);
});

console.log(visibleObjectsHtml);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

если добавляем метки через ymaps.ObjectManager то такой пример точно рабочий. при добавлении меток через ObjectManager мы можем включить произвольные данные в метку и когда получим список они будут нам доступны, очень удобно.

```
const objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            hasBalloon: false,
            clusterize: true,
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        });

objectManager.clusters.events.add('click', clusterClick);


function clusterClick(e) {
       objectManager.clusters.getById(e.get('objectId')).properties.geoObjects
    },
```